# How to synchronize a function between executors in spark to avoid concurrency in writing to Elastic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that will be called to write DataFrame to Elastic search using spark and scala. (DataFrame is created prior to function call)

```
def writeToES(dfForES: DataFrame, indexName: String, spark: SparkSession, conf: JSONObject) = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
    val doc_id_cols = Array("zip_id", "pattern_name", "row_index")
    if (indexName == conf.getString("elkParserIndex")) {
      println("Parser Index")
        .withColumn("row_index", col("line_number").cast(IntegerType))
        .write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
        .mode("append")
        .save(conf.getString("elkParserIndex"))
}
```

I have 5 executors with each having 3 cores. They call this function in parallel and elastic search gives an exception because it is unable to handle bulk parallel loads.

> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection
>   error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes

Since I am new to elastic so unable to handle this exception in elastic and want to handle in spark by avoiding the concurrency.
Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: repartition(1) surely?

Comment: it depends on your cluster configuration. have you setup spark and ES on same nodes? How many nodes in ES cluster, How many nodes in Spark, what amount of data are getting shuffle etc

Comment: @thebluephantom Thanks..I tried with coalesce(1) and it was working.. but did not understand how? What I thought is writing multiple small partitions is easier than writing big partition at once. can you please explain?

Comment: @Nikk I am having 3 nodes ES cluster and Spark cluster is separate having 1 large node, 3 workers having 5 cores each.

Comment: Not recommnded, goes to single partition and hence sequential.

Comment: @thebluephantom can you please explain what is not recommended and what is the better way to do it?

Comment: Answer not to your liking?

Answer (score 1):

Using .coalese(1) or .repartition(1) in your statement appropriately, will result in all data being shuffled to a single Executor on a Worker.

This means 1 process and no concurrency issues. It also means lower throughput.